# Webscraping multiple pages from a site gives just the home page contents?

Tags: python

I am trying to scrape the pages from the site https://www.rithmschool.com/blog. Though the contents of the 1st page are getting scraped, the problem with my code is - the same content is being scraped even for all the other pages of the site. Below is the code. 
Can anyone please help me fix the code.
My code

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from csv import writer

    html = requests.get('https://www.rithmschool.com/blog')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

    articles = soup.find_all('article')
    with open('scraped_rithm.csv', 'w') as f:
        data = writer(f)
        data.writerow(['Title','Link','Date'])
        for article in articles:
            title = article.find('a').get_text()
            link = article.find('a')['href']
            date = article.find('time')['datetime']
            data.writerow([title,link,date])

        spans = soup.find_all('span', {'class' : 'page'})
        for span in spans:
            if span.find('a'):
                urls = ((span.find('a')['href'])).split(',')
                for url in urls:
                    nw_urls = (f"https://www.rithmschool.com{url}")
                    print(nw_urls)
                    nw_response = requests.get(nw_urls)
                    nw_soup = BeautifulSoup(nw_response.text,'html.parser')
                    articles = soup.find_all('article')
                    for article in articles:
                        title = article.find('a').get_text()
                        link = article.find('a')['href']
                        date = article.find('time')['datetime']
                        data.writerow([title,link,date])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are still using the old `soup` object after creating a new `nw_soup` object

Try changing this from

```
                nw_soup = BeautifulSoup(nw_response.text,'html.parser')
                articles = soup.find_all('article')
```

to

```
                nw_soup = BeautifulSoup(nw_response.text,'html.parser')
                articles = nw_soup.find_all('article')
```

Comment: Wow!!! Thank you soooo very much Sunitha. It worked!!! I've been banging my head over it for a couple of days. BTW I'm a newbie to programming.

Can you pls help me with the below also:
I am using the below code to grab the links of the next page. However, I feel I am using a loooot of `for loops` in the process. Can u pls suggest a more efficient & minimal way of writing the same

Comment: `spans = soup.find_all('span', {'class' : 'page'})
        for span in spans:
            if span.find('a'):
                urls = ((span.find('a')['href'])).split(',')
                for url in urls:
                    nw_urls = (f"https://www.rithmschool.com{url}")
                    print(nw_urls)
                    nw_response = requests.get(nw_urls)`